# Using inheritance as a naming convention

Tags: c#, inheritance, naming-conventions, conventions

I was wondering about the use cases of inheritance. Specifically, I have a situation in C# where I have an Axis class where you can give the class a string name, among other properties. So you can write (new Axis(“X”)) to create an Axis named X.

Because usually you’ll want to create X, Y and Z axes, I feel inclined to create three subclasses of Axis named X, Y and Z, each of which specifies in the constructor what the Axis name is.

At present there is not a lot of code in the Axis class, so code reuse is pretty minimal (though of course that could change). And to be fair, it’s also not that much trouble to write (new Axis(“X”)) instead of (new X()).

Anyway, what I’m wondering about is whether there are any disadvantages to writing my code like this, or maybe if it’s just not common practice to do it like this. Much obliged!

Comment: Why not static properties on `Axis` called `X`, `Y` and `Z`? These could either return new instances of `Axis` or (optionally) shared instances (depends on whether `Axis` has mutable state). What do you think that these subclasses *add* that needs them to be different classes?

Comment: Generally, the reason to create a new class is to add functionality.  Sometimes, however, it can really aid readability if you create a "proxy name" like you're thinking of doing.  Try reading your code like a story, and decide based on what makes the story easier to understand.

Comment: The odds that this is correct design are not very good.  The direction of an axis is simply a property, there are not many reasons I can think of to override or add a method just because the axis is pointing in a different direction.  If you want to hide "X" then consider an object factory.

Comment: You might consider creating an emum with values X,Y,Z if you wish to restrict what values axis should be constructed with. You can pass the enum to an axis constructor, and set the name in there if you still need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imo it depends on what you're going to do with this value:

- Use it as a title: I can imagine a graph (are you creating a graph?) with an x-axis to represent *time* instead. A `string` constructor parameter is perfectly fine here, even if you decide to *always* name the x-axis "X".
- Use it to identify the axis: if other parts of the code actively look for an `"X"`-axis, you might want to use an enum instead, ie `AxisType.X`.
- nothing: if the application doesn't depend on this value, perhaps you could use "anonymous axes" instead, and leave out the parameter?

I wouldn't create a subclass unless each subclass has distinct behavior from the others.

Answer (score 0):

Like Damien mentioned, if it's only for making creating them simpler, it's probably a better idea to have a helper method/property for creating them.

```
public class Axis
{
    public Axis(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; }

    public static Axis X { get; } = new Axis("X");

    public static Axis CreateX() => new Axis("X");
}
```

If you have a property, you need to make sure Axis is immutable. You could always return a new one in the property, but that's not what a property should do.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

1. It is general consider poor practices to have variable names of x and y. names like this give other developers no insight into the nature of what the variable and it's use. The same principal should be used on class naming as well. Creating sub classes called x and y are not very useful names. I would lean on names like xAxis and yAxis to help provide clarity.
2. Does your XYZ coordinates have different properties or will be called by different methods that are specifically for each type? If not than why use different types. The the sub classes will not be equivalent or interchangeable. So any places that you plan on using them interchangeable would have either refer to base class any or have multiple version in code to handle each type.
3. If your just trying to short hand the instantiation of the class I would caution against is unless you are under some kind of sizing constraint.